Rich young kid kidnapped by two criminals and gets emotionally attached to them
I feel like this is a 90's or 80's movie, and I'm guessing it's a Hollywood/Disney type.
The plot is basically a young rich sheltered white kid getting kidnapped by these two criminals. The two (one?) criminals eventually befriend the kid and he likes them better than his parents; his parents were pretty wrapped up in their lives to pay too much attention to him.
I'm pretty sure one of the kidnappers buys/makes him a wooden owl. They also go to get him a dog, to which he replies his parents said he was allergic. They get him one anyway and realise his parents were lying. The end is the cops catching up with the kidnapper and the boy is sad. Can't fully remember.

Quite good in details, +1, but do you remember anything else, like how does character look, recognizable actor/actresses, dog breed etc.

Sounds like Me and the Kid from 1993 with Danny Aiello, Joe Pantoliano and Cathy Moriarty.

Two ex-cons, Harry (Aiello) and Roy (Pantoliano) execute a robbery they think will net them $250k. When they find the safe empty, Roy, decides to kidnap Gary, the eight year old son of their victims. Gary's hypochondriac mother has told the boy he is allergic to everything, keeping the lad from having a pet, going anywhere or doing anything. The boy is even home schooled and therefore has no friends his own age. When frustrated Roy wants to hurt and later kill the boy, Harry protects and then runs off with the kid leaving Roy tied up. Naturally Roy is angry, and being rather psychotic, he comes after Harry for revenge. Meanwhile, Gary has formed a strong attachment to Harry and the two have a wild adventure [...]

Roy also gets him a dog, despite his "allergies". Here's the trailer:




I did tried hard this time but failed to get the answer, can't upvote for now but might check the film despite low rating.

I'm almost certain I saw this once... Though I might be confusing it with "Dutch". The kid here seems really annoying, though. :/
